# ImportError: cannot import name 'HfApi'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

first time using hugging face transformers library and it's not getting through the import statement.
Running on Conda virtual environment Python 3.6

I also tried this below with the huggingface_hub library, and the error message is the same.

```
from huggingface_hub import HfApi

hf_api = HfApi()
models = hf_api.list_models()
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error stacktrace? Please also post what you are trying to import from `transformers`. Have you installed the packages before you run those lines (i.e. `!pip install transformers`)?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue on my Python 3.6 environment. Installing hugging face on an environment with greater Python version was solved the issue.